# correlation results display issue- math function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, math, minmax

Though code runs well, but results not displayed. Did I miss anything?

```
# Independent variables
x1 = 'a'
x2 = 'b'

# Dependent variable
y = 'c'

# Pairings
x1y = cor.loc[ x1, y ]
x2y = cor.loc[ x2, y ]
x1x2 = cor.loc[ x1, x2 ]

Rx1x2y = math.sqrt((abs(x1y**2) + abs(x2y**2) - 2*x1y*x2y*x1x2) / (1- 
abs(x1x2**2)) )
R2 = Rx1x2y**2

# Calculate adjusted R-squared
n = len(data) # Number of rows
k = 2       # Number of independent variables
R2_adj = 1 - ( ((1-R2)*(n-1)) / (n-k-1) )
```

Above codes ran well nut no results displayed here. I was expecting R2,R2_adj values in output

Comment: Have you tried to `print` them with a simple `print(R2)` for example ?

Comment: print works, thanks Alexandre!